# for loop going beyond the compare limit

Tags: for-loop, groovy

This feels so stupid but what is wrong with this code? My for loop runs till 55

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("StepName#ResponseAsXml")

def cnt = holder["count(//Results/ResultSet/Row)"]
log.info "Row count is: " + cnt

for(int i = 1; i<=cnt; i++){
    x = x + 1
}

log.info "Loop ran for: " + x
```

The output is as below:

Mon Aug 19 12:38:04 ADT 2013:INFO:Row count is: 7

Mon Aug 19 12:38:04 ADT 2013:INFO:Loop ran for: 56

Edit...
Lets try something different, forget the variable x and just print the row at like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<cnt; i++){
    log.info "At row: " + i.toString()
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Mon Aug 19 12:57:41 ADT 2013:INFO:Row count: 7
Mon Aug 19 12:51:03 ADT 2013:INFO:At row: 0
Mon Aug 19 12:51:03 ADT 2013:INFO:At row: 1
Mon Aug 19 12:51:03 ADT 2013:INFO:At row: 2
Mon Aug 19 12:51:03 ADT 2013:INFO:At row: 3
.
.
.
.
Mon Aug 19 12:51:03 ADT 2013:INFO:At row: 54
```

Comment: What do you initialise `x` to?

Comment: After the edit: What's the issue?  You have `55` things, and so you do `0`, `1`, `...`, `54`.  That's 55 things...

Comment: You can also replace `log.info "At row: " + i.toString()` with `log.info "At row $i"` (and save yourself some typing) ;-)

Comment: I do not have 55 things i only have 7. Before running the for loop i also print the value of cnt and it always shows 7.
Mon Aug 19 13:06:31 ADT 2013:INFO:Row count: 7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `cnt` variable is of type String ("7").  The ASCII numeric value of "7" is 55, so that is why your loop counts up to 54.

Try the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i<(cnt as int); i++){
    println "At row: " + i.toString()
}
```

Comment: The log statement shouldn't have affected the type of the variable.  Looks like com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder#get(Object) returns an Object.  You could add a cnt.getClass().getName() log print right after assigning the variable to see what XmlHolder is returning.